# Reference: Every Scheme is Derived Affine

Tags: algebraic-geometry, noncommutative-algebra, derived-categories

I'm trying to track down a reference for the following claim, found in Kaledin's lectures *Methods in Noncommutative Algebraic Geometry*:

> As it turns out, an arbitrary scheme $X$ also appears already on this level [*viz* regarding a differential-graded algebra as a `noncommutative variety']: the derived category $\mathcal{D}(X)$ of quasicoherent sheaves on $X$ is equivalent to the derived category $\mathcal{D}(A)$ of a certain (non-canonical) DG algebra $A$. The rough slogan for this is that “every scheme is derived-affine”.

This seems to harken back to classic papers by Kontsevich, Kapranov/Ciocan-Fontanine, but I struggle to find a clear reference; I understand the equivalence of categories between derived affine schemes and commutative differential-graded rings, but this statement is slightly different, and more general. $A$ is an arbitrary DG algebra over field of characteristic zero and the original scheme may not be affine. The author admits he did not feel obligated to cite anything, which is fine since he provided these high quality lecture notes.

Comment: This is a bad slogan. Derived-affine should mean a commutative dg algebra, but the dg algebra in this claim is not guaranteed to be and won’t in general be commutative. It’s also a bad slogan because the natural notion of morphism on the two sides of the comparison are different.

Comment: But is it a bad slogan for non-commutative geometry? That's the context of the remark, that we seek an analogue of algebraic variety over very general algebras, and dg algebras are proposed as a viable candidate because of this non-canonical equivalence; in the commutative case we recover the classical one we know and love.

Comment: How about the replacement "every scheme is noncommutatively affine"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Corollary 3.1.8 in [Bondal - Van Den Bergh paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0204218.pdf).  The slogan also first appears in that paper (just after the statement of the corollary).

P.S. Let’s leave judging whether the slogan is “good” to the experts! Indeed that slogan permeates the school of “noncommutative algebraic geometry” of Kontsevich et al for many years, maybe one can say it is a “raison d’etre” of this school.